# Aggregated Weighted Sum with a Step Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

I have appended an aggregated row at the end, that calculates the mean of the column, while ignoring null values. See my code here:

```
repayments_amt_pivot.loc['Aggregated'] = repayments_amt_pivot.iloc[:, 3:].mean(skipna=True)
```

However, instead of a simple mean for the aggregated row, I actually need to calculate a weighted sum of the percentages multipled by the proportion in principal_due_per_month.

In this case, for Month 4, row 0 would be multipled by (27,845 / 27,845 + 310,506 + 659,705 + 1,433,121).

For Month 3, row 4 would be multiplied by (1,941,036 / 27,845 + 310,506 + 659,705 + 1,433,121 + 1,941,036)

etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure this one out!

See the following for screenshots of how to calculate in excel.

Data:

```
    pd.DataFrame([{'$ Amount Due': 27845.312793586978,
  'Month 0': 56.479872661140476,
  'Month 1': 92.94027983726657,
  'Month 2': 100.00000000000003,
  'Month 3': 100.00000000000003,
  'Month 4': 100.00000000000003},
 {'$ Amount Due': 310505.5597382864,
  'Month 0': 78.34839385064039,
  'Month 1': 79.58303224427453,
  'Month 2': 79.58303224427453,
  'Month 3': 81.43498983472573,
  'Month 4': 92.54673537743292},
 {'$ Amount Due': 659705.2173778547,
  'Month 0': 90.79718901057414,
  'Month 1': 97.8418387417451,
  'Month 2': 97.85768670717538,
  'Month 3': 97.85768670717538,
  'Month 4': 97.85768670717538},
 {'$ Amount Due': 1433121.318250646,
  'Month 0': 91.7207168764003,
  'Month 1': 94.34283888419282,
  'Month 2': 94.51326381568556,
  'Month 3': 94.8581612152927,
  'Month 4': 94.91544740629973},
 {'$ Amount Due': 1941036.1276433321,
  'Month 0': 79.75029644420579,
  'Month 1': 85.62252846197367,
  'Month 2': 86.59251760542142,
  'Month 3': 86.70920561577343,
  'Month 4': np.nan},
 {'$ Amount Due': 3448302.2801859295,
  'Month 0': 75.83697471065258,
  'Month 1': 83.6700011095642,
  'Month 2': 86.16217213969533,
  'Month 3': np.nan,
  'Month 4': np.nan},
 {'$ Amount Due': 3190042.0279137697,
  'Month 0': 76.69574360823212,
  'Month 1': 85.4625418697537,
  'Month 2': np.nan,
  'Month 3': np.nan,
  'Month 4': np.nan},
 {'$ Amount Due': 2614440.2956102462,
  'Month 0': 74.87175589142862,
  'Month 1': np.nan,
  'Month 2': np.nan,
  'Month 3': np.nan,
  'Month 4': np.nan}])
```

Comment: In the first screenshot you are doing forward sum (for 4 months. Is that because it's Month 4 column?) but in the second screenshot, you are doing the cumulative sum of all the months before. Is that a discrepancy or is there a logic I am not getting?

Comment: In the first screenshot, I only use cells D4:D7 because, in  column I (month 4) there are only values for cells I4:I7.

In the first screenshot, relating to column G (month 2), I use cells D4:D9 because, in column G (month 2) there are values for cells G4:G9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[8, "Month 0":] = [(df["Month "+str(i)]*df[df["Month "+str(i)].notnull()]["$ Amount Due"]/df[df["Month "+str(i)].notnull()]["$ Amount Due"].sum()).sum() for i in range(5)]

df

    $ Amount Due       Month 0     Month 1      Month 2     Month 3     Month 4
0   2.784531e+04    56.479873   92.940280   100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
1   3.105056e+05    78.348394   79.583032    79.583032   81.434990   92.546735
2   6.597052e+05    90.797189   97.841839    97.857687   97.857687   97.857687
3   1.433121e+06    91.720717   94.342839    94.513264   94.858161   94.915447
4   1.941036e+06    79.750296   85.622528    86.592518   86.709206         NaN
5   3.448302e+06    75.836975   83.670001    86.162172         NaN         NaN
6   3.190042e+06    76.695744   85.462542          NaN         NaN         NaN
7   2.614440e+06    74.871756         NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN
8            NaN    78.823057   86.680023    88.573969   90.772494   95.469538
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be:

```
months = df.iloc[:, 1:]                    # dataframe of months only
due_row = months.where(months.isna(), df['$ Amount Due'], axis=0)    # single due values
due_sum = due_row.sum()                    # summed due values

(months*due_row/due_sum).sum()             # sum of product and quotient like requested

#Month 0    78.823057
#Month 1    86.680023
#Month 2    88.573969
#Month 3    90.772494
#Month 4    95.469538
#dtype: float64
```

and if it should be attached to the dataframe as last row:

```
df.loc['Aggregated', df.columns[1:]] = (months*due_row/due_sum).sum().values

#            $ Amount Due    Month 0     ...         Month 3     Month 4
#0           2.784531e+04  56.479873     ...      100.000000  100.000000
#1           3.105056e+05  78.348394     ...       81.434990   92.546735
#2           6.597052e+05  90.797189     ...       97.857687   97.857687
#3           1.433121e+06  91.720717     ...       94.858161   94.915447
#4           1.941036e+06  79.750296     ...       86.709206         NaN
#5           3.448302e+06  75.836975     ...             NaN         NaN
#6           3.190042e+06  76.695744     ...             NaN         NaN
#7           2.614440e+06  74.871756     ...             NaN         NaN
#Aggregated           NaN  78.823057     ...       90.772494   95.469538
```

---

supplemental edit:

this code is (a little) shorter, IMO much cleaner to almost self explaining, and faster:

```
timings:
AnanayMital :   0.0209
SpghttCd :      0.00538
```